# Performance implications when using singleton from non-singletons in Java?

Tags: java

Suppose there are several instances of a class simultaneously calling service methods defined in a singleton class.

Can some one explain to me what happens at the low level when a method is called in a singleton when that method is already being executed by some other instance of the class? I am thinking that JVM would block the caller until the current caller is done with the method. Is this right?

Would it improve performance if we move some of the methods in the singleton class to define them within the class needing such methods?

Would it improve performance if singleton is changed to non-singleton allowing each instance of a class needing to call the service methods in another class to create its own instance of the service class?

Assume of course singleton is stateless.

Consider the situation multiple threads calling service methods in the singleton.

Comment: For someone new to the forum 69% is good, however he has 26 questions not accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Generally service objects are singleton and are stateless. So There is no impact on it. if you have multiple object instead one per class then I think it would fill the heap more.

Answer (score 3):

A singleton is just a constraint you place on the number of instances a class can have.  There is no specific support or different behaviour a Singleton has in the JVM, or the CPU of your machine.

> Can some one explain to me what happens when a method is called in a singleton when that method is already being executed by some other instance of the class?

Nothing special.

> Would it improve performance if we move some of the methods in the singleton class to define them within the class needing such methods?

No, however moving code out of a Singleton may improve readability of the Singleton. If it make the code clearer, it worth doing.

Answer (score 3):

> Can some one explain to me what happens at the low level when a method
>   is called in a singleton when that method is already being executed by
>   some other instance of the class? I am thinking that JVM would block
>   the caller until the current caller is done with the method. Is this
>   right?

Answer: JVM does not automatically synchronize access to singleton objects method, if that is what your are assuming here. This conflicts with one of uses of singletons, to let many threads execute a method without instantiating objects for each new thread wanting to execute that method.

---

> Would it improve performance if we move some of the methods in the
>   singleton class to define them within the class needing such methods?

Answer: No, moving a method from a singleton to a new non-singleton class is good only if this method is in any way modifying instance variables of the singleton or the non-singleton class. Otherwise let it be in the singleton class. If you move it, classes using it will have to call it in non-singleton way. Resulting in unnecessary object creation.

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by Peter Lawrey and Jigar Joshi, there is nothing special about a singleton object, and if it in indeed stateless then there is nothing to worry about. If it has state then you need to ensure that the methods are thread-safe, for example by using synchronization. If your method is `synchronized` then further calls will indeed block until the first is complete, but this will not happen otherwise. I recommend "Java Concurrency in Practice" as a good introduction to writing multi-threaded code in Java.

As for performance, with a stateless singleton that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently, there is no advantage (and some additional overhead) to constructing multiple objects instead. In general, I would focus on clarity of design first, then measure the performance and perhaps try out different structures if there is a problem.